# FatCow and iPage real deal?

Tags: web-hosting

I need a cheap host that I can upgrade if needed for a  startup.  From searching, FatCow and iPage seem reliable and inexpensive web hosting services with a Unix OS and good bandwidth + disk space.  I suspect they were bought from the same company.

They propose to offer unlimited bandwidth/disc space and perks like AdSense/Facebook credit however, they're packages range from 1-3 years @ 3.15 USD/mo, there isn't a monthly package but they do allow you to cancel at anytime and there servers run on wind-mill generated energy which is a plus.

I was suspicious because I couldnt seem to find one negative review about them, just affiliate pages until I read a review explaining they're strict policies on copywritten data.

Has anyone experience with one of these two hosts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use iPage, and have used them for several sites over the past few years. The packages they offer should be enough for almost anything you would be doing. The advertised sale price is only for the first term, after that they charge the regular price. So the longer you pick when you sign up the longer you get the discounted price. It usually says the regular price on their homepage as well.

I recommend them to the non-profit groups that I volunteer with if they are looking for a web host. So far I am a happy customer.

Also, iPage is owned by Endurance International Group, which own many hosting companies, including:

AccountSupport

ApolloHosting

BizLand

BlueDomino

BlueHost

DomainHost

Dot5Hosting

Easy CGI

eHost

EntryHost

FastDomain

FatCow

FreeYellow

Globat

HostCentric

HostMonster

HostYourSite

HyperMart

IMOutdoorsHosting

iPage

Ipower

IPowerWeb

Justhost

Netfirms

Networkshosting

PowWeb

PureHost

ReadyHosting

Spry

StartLogic

USANetHosting

VirtualAvenue

VPSLink

WebHost4Life

Webstrikesolutions

Xeran

YourWebHosting

Comment: This is good, thanks.  I had no idea.  It's for a startup that's probably getting transferred to our server when it's running so I need something like hostgator w/ monthly payments.